# Javascript Cookies, set after site close or 

Tags: javascript, cookies

Ok, this might sound strange but i need to somehow set cookies on site close, or maybe if somoeone knows different logic i could use to solve my problem:

I am using open source solution to track clicks on my site - http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html .Ive change this script to add few more filters for every click such as what OS is user using, referrers, and is user new or returning for which I am using cookies - using mostly this script for cookies http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/firstimpression-js-library-detecting-new-visitors/ .

Now the problem i have is this. First time you come to site and click, you will be marked as new user, but just with next click u are marked as returning user. Because cookie was set at start and with each click, through GET i am sending these parameters , one of them is testing if cookie exists on site, if it does it sends that you are returning visitor. You can see at this debug link - http://gjakovljevic.com/index.html?debugclickheat , at the bottom it asks "New = yes/no".

So I need solution that will mark user as new with whole first visit, not just with first click, so once he leaves site and comes back, this time his clicks will be marked as clicks from returning visitor.

Here is the link to full script -
http://www.putuj.org/clickheat/js/clickheat-original.js

line 167 is cookie function and line 239 is testing if visitor is new or not.

I hope that i explained well. I am playing with this heatmap script, managed to change and add alot of nice features but I stuck with cookies :)

Answer (score 0):

well the best solution for me here is the following

1. have a database record of the new visitor, from its ip address and all the details you can gather on its browser he or she is using
2. then set a duration where in the new visitors's record is considered as a returning visitor
3. if the user returned with the same ip address and details check if the user already came back is already out of the set duration so it means the user is already a returning user, else he is a new user.

Comment: Ah yes, that would be possible if i was using DB, but for now script is using simple log file to store logs, i cant use DB, unless i change it, but that might be possible altho would take some time as system wasnt made to use DB at all, just writing data into log files. But thanks, if i dont figure it out, i might do it this way